# Is this a legal Scrabble play?

Tags: scrabble

[image]

My sister played the three circled letters on her turn. Is it legal?

Answer (score 14):

**Nope.**

From the [official rules](https://scrabble.hasbro.com/en-us/rules) (emphasis mine):

> All letters played on a turn **must be placed in one row across or down the board**, to form at least one complete word. If, at the same time, they touch others letters in adjacent rows, those must also form complete words, crossword fashion, with all such letters. The player gets full credit for all words formed or modified on his or her turn.

So it is not legal to play those three tiles in a single turn, since they are not all in the same row or column.

Note, however, that "Fe" is a legal scrabble word.  Your sister could legally play "Fee" across and form "Fe" down.

Comment: Is "Fe" a legal word because of the symbol for Iron?

Comment: According to the [Scrabble dictionary](https://scrabble.hasbro.com/en-us/tools#dictionary) it is "a Hebrew letter."